# Why does history back not work on <a> onclick in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why in Firefox, `window.history.back()` does work on a button:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Go back</button>
```

But it does not work for a link:

```
<a onclick="window.history.back()">Go back</a>
```

What is the difference?

An example illustrating this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>First page</h1>
  <br/>
  <a href="second.html">Second</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Second page</h1>
  <a href="third.html">Third</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back (button)</button>
  <br/>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back (a)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**third.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Third page</h1>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back (button)</button>
  <br/>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back (a)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Scenario:**

1. Run index.html and click **Second**.
2. On second.html click **Third**.
3. On third.html click **Go back (a)**.
4. On second.html click **Go back (a)**. Boom! I'm on the third.html, and not on the first.html!!!

**[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/erszqHsAkmk0yR1quzYB?p=preview)** (Note! Run it on Firefox)

If you use **Go back (button)** it works. What is the difference in  `<a onclick` and `<button onclick` in this case?

Comment: Instead of `onclick="window.history.back()"` why don't you consider using `href="javascript:window.history.back()"`?

Comment: But I did not ask about the bypass. And I ask why it works that way?

Comment: see the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: it seems to working fine in Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: I have just tested it on Firefox 25.0.1 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are facing this issue ([quoted from vikku.info](http://vikku.info/codesnippets/javascript/why-javascript-historyback-toggles-between-two-pages/)):

> But what had happened when i press the back button after navigating to
>   various pages was i got locked between the last two navigated pages.

Someone in the comments hit the nail on this issue.

- When you create the `onclick` attribute, you are attaching an additional event handler for clicking a link. However, the browser will still handle some *native* logic, so it will still add the current page to the history;
- When you pass in specific javascript into the `href` attribute, you are actually overriding the *native* logic of the browser, so it won't add the current page to the history;

**SIMPLE, DIRTY SOLUTION**

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

---

**IMPROVED SOLUTION**

I've also created an example ([Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/okn2uK0IvewxpTy6nqyf?p=preview)) that makes use of the native `preventDefault` functionality ([MDN on preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)). In that case, it is not needed to write javascript in the `href` attribute. Now, you can support users that are not using javascript by linking to, for example, the homepage. You better also avoid using inline event handlers.

HTML:

```
<a href="index.html" id="backButton">Back</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var backbutton = document.getElementById("backButton");
backbutton.onclick = function(e){
  e = e || window.event; // support  for IE8 and lower
  e.preventDefault(); // stop browser from doing native logic
  window.history.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be related to the `href` attribute of the `a` tag, that get interpreted as a next step in navigation (even if you go back in history).

Try removing the `href` attribute from the `a`.

As you see, this way it works:

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Xt6INtuiqpuzdvgvxWs?p=preview)

You do need just to fix CSS for the `a` now

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$("#back").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
})
```

**or**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"> Link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

Check the **[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)** for more details.

Comment: Could you explain what difference it will make?

Comment: would let it to go just one step back(just previous visited page.)

Comment: Your answer does not work! But I did not ask about the bypass. And I ask why it works that way. Workaround is <a href = "javascript: window.history.back ()".

Comment: Isn't that what `window.history.back()` does?