# Can't manipulate the browser history to previous page JS

Tags: javascript, html

How to navigate to previous browser url on button click?

Already tried this suggestions:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

[Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Problem is that with window.history.go(-1) it navigates to homepage '/' url not to the previous page url.

**Code:**

```
<a class="link-terminal" href="" onclick="goToPreviousPage(); return false;"></a>

<script>
   function goToPreviousPage() {
      window.history.go(-1);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Comment: Already tried all suggestions in this link, doesn't work in my case

Comment: Be certain, .go and .back work as intended.  Clearly the history isn't what you expect, start there and inspect page loads etc.

Comment: Missed this - have goToPreviousPage return false.  Also, see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422770/returning-false-from-click-handler-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: There's likely something else going on in your application if those functions don't work. Check for errors in the console, let us know if you're using some kind of framework, etc.

Comment: After adding return false; it navigates to homepage '/' route, but not to previous visited url. I need to use plain javascript in this case.

Comment: Result after click: Navigating to homepage, page title shows last visited page title as it should, but page url not changed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a class="link-terminal" href="" onclick="goToPreviousPage(); return false;">go back</a>

<script>
   function goToPreviousPage() {
      window.history.go(-1);
   }
</script>
</body>
```

Be sure you add the `return false;` part in your `onclick`.

This should fix your problem.

Also, in your code `//window.history.go(-1))` has one too many "`)`" at the end.

Comment: Now it navigates to homepage '/' route, but not to previous visited url.

Comment: Result after click: Navigating to homepage, page title shows last visited page title as it should, but page url not changed.

Comment: i googled around a bit and i found this post that looks very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421071/5497395 . are you running firefox ?

Comment: Cant use that approach, console error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'javascript:window.history.back();' cannot be created in a document with origin`

Comment: Adding javascript, e.preventDefault(), navigates to specified href="/" url not to previous page and url not updating, just page title shows correct previous page title